# Batch file - list files and save as variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need a batch file (.bat) that list all txt files from a directory and list them as variables and in a new menu so I can run them.

Folder contains:

```
test1.php, test1.txt test2.txt, image.bmp
```

Then the result in the menu should be:

```
Press 1 for test1
Press 2 for test2
```

It should also look in subfolders.

Comment: puh - DOS is ooold. There are no commands to do that. Well, if you were on Windows `cmd`, then it would be easy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming, you are on Windows (as DOS is "out of office" since decades...):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set n=0
for /r %%a in (*.txt) do (
  set /a n+=1
  set "menu_!n!=%%a"
  echo press !n! for %%~nxa
)
set /p "take=your choice:"
!menu_%take%!
```

For help, see `for /?` and `set /?`

Note that this won't work on DOS. Even if all the commands actually exist in DOS, their capability is not the same (and of course there is no [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) in DOS).

Comment: yeah, `start`, `notepad` .... depends. Usually, `.txt` files are associated with notepad.exe. Probably a pair of quotes would be useful too.

Comment: Hi! Cool, that's exactly what i wanted :-) Thx